# P4PORT Perforce client error in Windows 10

Tags: perforce

I am new to perforce and i am trying to connect to perforce remote server but i am getting error as:

Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        TCP connect to : failed.
        connect: :: WSAETIMEDOUT.

I tries setting the port also but still I am facing this issue.
Can someone please suggest where the things might be going wrong?

Comment: Could be a number of reasons. Did you set this up yourself? If so, verify the port # is correct. If not, speak to your Perforce Administrator. If you are running on Windows, run "p4 set" to see what--if anything--is set. This might at least give you a clue as to what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message it looks like your `P4PORT` is set to just a single `:` character, which can't be correct.  Do:

```
p4 set P4PORT=your.perforce.server:1666
p4 info
```

where `your.perforce.server` is the address of your Perforce server.  (1666 is the default port number for a Perforce server.)  If you don't know what it is, talk to your Perforce admin.  Once the `P4PORT` is set correctly, `p4 info` should show you the server info.

For example:

```
C:\>p4 set P4PORT=:

C:\>p4 info
Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        TCP connect to : failed.
        No such host is known.

C:\>p4 set P4PORT=public.perforce.com:1666

C:\>p4 info
User name: Samwise
Client name: COMPY386
Client host: COMPY386
Client unknown.
Current directory: c:\
Peer address: 52.119.114.217:62631
Client address: 52.119.114.217
Server date: 2019/09/20 09:36:02 -0700 PDT
Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2019.1/1845410 (2019/08/28)
ServerID: guru_maser
Server services: standard
Server license: Licensed
Case Handling: sensitive
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the p4 port using 'p4 set' and it is set correctly. But still i am facing the connection issue.